# Is there a word to replace the phrase for 'couldn't have been more different'?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

I don't think the phrase is formal and academic enough, but I can't think of a word  to replace it.

I want to say something like this: The two frogs both agreed that they needed to fight, but their fighting strategies "**couldn't have been more different**."

Comment: You can move a rung higher on the formality ladder by replacing "couldn't" with "could not," yielding the formally impeccable phrase, "could not have been more different." [_The Edinburgh History of Scottish Literature, Volume 2: Enlightenment, Britain, and Empire (1707–1918)_](https://books.google.com/books?id=0OWqBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA90&dq=%22could+not+have+been+more+different%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjIzqvEwIzMAhUO62MKHa0sC3s4FBDoAQhSMAk#v=onepage&q=%22could%20not%20have%20been%20more%20different%22&f=false), from Edinburgh University Press, uses this form of the phrase twice within 22 pages.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of modifiers to "different" which will work:

- *completely* different
- *entirely* different

etc.

Depending on the sense, you could go for *opposite*.

Another single word is *[diametric](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/diametric)*, one sense of which is *completely opposed*. Or, in that same vein, maybe *[antithetical](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/antithetical)*, which is *being in direct and unequivocal opposition*.

Comment: I was thinking ***diametrically opposed*** — so, is that redundant?

Comment: @Scott On reflection, I don't think "diametric" necessary has the sense of opposition without context, and so if that context isn't otherwise there, using "diametrically opposed" makes sense. It might be a *little* redundant, but it's certainly a very common phrase.

Answer (score 2):

**Disparate**

> markedly distinct in quality or character

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disparate)

(Similar to incongruous as aforementioned.)

Answer (score 2):

- [Antithetical](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/antithetical)?
- [Contrasting](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/contrasting)?

Or perhaps similar phrases:

- The [inverse](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inverse)?
- In [stark](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stark) contrast?
- Absolutely [incompatible](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/incompatible)?
- Polar opposites?

Or for that matter, [antipodean](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/antipodean) \ [antipodal](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/antipodal)?

Answer (score 1):

Consider ***incongruous***.

> : strange because of not agreeing with what is usual or expected
>   <sub>[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/incongruous)</sub>